# Relaunch GUI every time when open Settings

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, gnome

Issue reproducible on 18.xx Ubuntu 16.xx is fine.
So most of all problem in GNOME.

Issue:
Every time when I open Settings, all UI is restart and I appeared on login screen. 
Here is also Syslog(but I'm not sure what actually part of issue):

```
Jan 14 19:41:47 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jan 14 19:41:47 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-shell[11306]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js 1052]: unreachable code after return statement
Jan 14 19:41:47 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gsd-xsettings[11510]: Failed to get current display configuration state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" doe
s not exist
Jan 14 19:41:47 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gsd-sharing[11506]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-user-share-webdav.service not loaded.
Jan 14 19:41:47 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gsd-sharing[11506]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
Jan 14 19:41:47 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gsd-sharing[11506]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
Jan 14 19:41:47 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gsd-color[10756]: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Не удалось открыть файл «/home/mhr/.local/share/icc/edid-4ea41a8c287ab0e4717eecd08b2e6cc4.icc»: Отказано в доступе
Jan 14 19:41:47 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[11115]: Entering running state
Jan 14 19:41:47 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 dbus-daemon[1047]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service' requested by ':1.1639' (uid=1000 p
id=11546 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-keyboard " label="unconfined")
Jan 14 19:41:47 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 systemd[1]: Starting Locale Service...
Jan 14 19:41:47 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 nvidia-settings-autostart.desktop[11611]: ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
Jan 14 19:41:47 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 nvidia-settings-autostart.desktop[11611]: ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).
Jan 14 19:41:47 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 nvidia-settings-autostart.desktop[11611]: ERROR: Error querying connected displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).
Jan 14 19:41:47 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 dbus-daemon[11109]: [session uid=1000 pid=11109] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.FileManager1' requested by ':1.62' (uid=1000 pid=11602 comm="nautilus-desktop "
 label="unconfined")
Jan 14 19:41:48 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 dbus-daemon[1047]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jan 14 19:41:48 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jan 14 19:41:48 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 dbus-daemon[11109]: [session uid=1000 pid=11109] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1'
Jan 14 19:41:48 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 kernel: [14082.842811] rfkill: input handler disabled
Jan 14 19:41:48 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-shell[11306]: Some code accessed the property 'introspectBusObject' on the module 'util'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This w
as previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time bei
ng, but please fix your code anyway.
Jan 14 19:41:48 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 dbus-daemon[1047]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
Jan 14 19:41:48 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 systemd[1]: Started Locale Service.
Jan 14 19:41:48 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-shell[11306]: Some code accessed the property 'dbusNodeImplementsInterfaces' on the module 'util'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the modul
e. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the
 time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Jan 14 19:41:48 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-shell[11306]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Jan 14 19:41:48 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gsd-color[10756]: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Не удалось открыть файл «/home/mhr/.local/share/icc/edid-4ea41a8c287ab0e4717eecd08b2e6cc4.icc»: Отказано в доступе
Jan 14 19:41:48 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11073]: (II) modeset(0): Disabling kernel dirty updates, not required.
Jan 14 19:41:49 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-shell[11306]: GNOME Shell started at Mon Jan 14 2019 19:41:47 GMT+0200 (EET)
Jan 14 19:41:49 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 goa-daemon[11393]: /org/gnome/OnlineAccounts/Accounts/account_1544191370_2: Setting AttentionNeeded to TRUE because EnsureCredentials() failed with: Bad Request (rest-proxy-error-quark, 400)
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 at-spi-bus-launcher[10675]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1024"
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 at-spi-bus-launcher[10675]:       after 21 requests (21 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop' killed by signal 15
:
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 ibus-daemon[10709]: GChildWatchSource: Exit status of a child process was requested but ECHILD was received by waitpid(). See the documentation of g_child_watch_source_new() for possible causes.
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-shell[10638]: Connection to xwayland lost
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gsd-color[11542]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_AU_Optronics_gdm_121
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session[10623]: gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 gnome-session-binary[10623]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@121.service: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 121...
Jan 14 19:41:53 mhr-HP-ZBook-15-G5 systemd[10576]: Stopping Accessibility services bus...
:
```

I also think problem can be in my driver.
I have latest version of HP ZBooG G5 with Nvidia P2000 and 4k display. Ubuntu 16.04 is working well.

Comment: @codito thank you for editing, i don't finad a way how to format it beautiful.

Comment: take a look at this page: **https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting.**